How to pass input from CAPL script to a Python script and execute it
I wrote a script to search a keyword in  a logs, which is working perfectly fine. but the thing is if i want to find another string i have to make a clone and make it for the other one. i am automating my test cases so i can not wait for the window to show up and ask me what keyword i want to search so i was hoping if there is any way i can just write my keyword with python script in capl function. so that python script remains same.
import os
import glob
import datetime
import sys

def get_latest_dlt_file(folder_path):
    # Get a list of all .dlt files in the folder
    dlt_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.dlt"))
    # Filter out directories, get modification times, and sort by modification time
    dlt_files = [(f, os.path.getmtime(f)) for f in dlt_files if os.path.isfile(f)]
    dlt_files.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # Return the path of the latest modified .dlt file, if any
    return dlt_files[0][0] if dlt_files else None

def dlt_to_txt_converter(dlt_file_path, txt_file_path):
    try:
        with open(dlt_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as dlt_file:
            dlt_content = dlt_file.read()

        with open(txt_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as txt_file:
            txt_file.write(dlt_content)

        print(f"Conversion successful! Contents have been written to {txt_file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

def search_string_line_by_line(txt_file, search_string):
    found = False
    try:
        try:
            with open(txt_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
                print(f"Opened file: {txt_file} with utf-8 encoding")
                for line in file:
                    if search_string in line:
                        found = True
                        break
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            with open(txt_file, 'r', encoding='latin1', errors='ignore') as file:
                print(f"Opened file: {txt_file} with latin1 encoding")
                for line in file:
                    if search_string in line:
                        found = True
                        break

        with open("DLT_Message.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as message_found:
            if found:
                message_found.write("1")
                print("String found in the text file.")
            else:
                message_found.write("0")
                print("String not found in the text file.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File not found: {txt_file}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify the folder containing the .dlt files
    folder_path = r"C:\Software\Python"

    # Get the path of the latest modified .dlt file in the folder
    latest_dlt_file = get_latest_dlt_file(folder_path)

    if latest_dlt_file:
        # Define the path for the converted .txt file
        txt_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(latest_dlt_file), os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(latest_dlt_file))[0] + ".txt")

        # Define the search string
        
search_string = "ALT-INFO"

        # Convert the latest .dlt file to .txt
        dlt_to_txt_converter(latest_dlt_file, txt_file_path)

        # Search for the string in the .txt file
        search_string_line_by_line(txt_file_path, search_string)
    else:
        print("No .dlt files found in the specified folder.")
        
    # Close the terminal
    os._exit(0)


CAPL
void Search_Logs()
{
    sysExecCmd("search_logs.py", "", putty_pythonScriptPath);
}


The second argument to sysExecCmd are the parameters passed to the executable on the command line. In your python script you can use sys.args to access the command line arguments.

If I understand correctly you have written a python script to search for a string: search_string. And you are trying to use this python script in a CAPL script.
To get the search_string from CAPL you could pass it as a command line argument.
# search_string = "ALT-INFO" # <- replace this with the next line
search_string = sys.argv[1]

to use this script now use (command as cli I don't know how CAPL's sysExecCmd works)
python search_logs.py ALT-INFO

